# CSS show div on hover not working

Tags: html, css, hover, show

I can't get the div to show on hover over the other div. I'm sure I'm missing something really basic.

```
.sidebarRightWork:hover .description {
display:block;}

.description { width:100%; height:100%; margin: 0 auto; position:absolute; background-color:#D4D4D4; z-index:15; display:none;}
```

[image]

[image]

*EDIT*

As you see, when you hover over 'information' nothing happens like it does in your fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/f1c3vc0y/3/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `+` ([adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)) selector, because `.description` is not a descendant of `.sidebarRightWork`, but the next sibling. Just like:

```
.sidebarRightWork:hover + .description {
    display:block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/d1pm4tpj/2/)

**EDIT:**

Then you need also:

```
.sidebarRightWork:hover + .description, .description:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

[**DEMO2**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/f1c3vc0y/2/)

Note that I have positioned `.description` to fill the entire screen. You can do it the way you want ;)

Comment: There's this flickering now when the mouse moves slightly over the trigger div. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: I have created a [new demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/d1pm4tpj/3/) with `.description` inside `.sidebarRightWork`, and leave the CSS selector as it was at the beginning. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear! I've got the .sidebarRightWork at a 270deg angle but I want the .description to appear in the middle of the viewport the right way up. https://jsfiddle.net/f1c3vc0y/

Comment: See my edit and my [new demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/f1c3vc0y/2/). I think it's better to keep `.description` out of `.sidebarRightWork` ;) And please delete the answer you have posted and add the image in your question.

Comment: @Imgonzalves  When I scroll down and hover over the sidebar it still only occupies the original screen and leaves the rest empty. It doesn't seem to recalcuate the height. I added a pic up top to explain. :)

Comment: You are looking for something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/f1c3vc0y/3/). I only set `position: fixed;` to `.description` element. If it's not what you want please explain a bit more.

Comment: @Imgonzalves   That's weird. Now it doesn't even do anything. https://jsfiddle.net/7mx8mmLd/1/   (Click that img icon just above modalNo2). I'm so confused.

Comment: I can't see the image, but you need to define what you want clearly.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand anything what you are saying :(

Comment: So you're fiddle is correct (https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/f1c3vc0y/3/). However, when you try to replicate it on my fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/7mx8mmLd/1/), it doesn't work. When you hover over 'information' the description does not show up. You can try for yourself in the fiddle I provided by (1) press that img icon and then (2) hovering your mouse over 'information'. :)

Comment: That happen because you have `.description` inside `.sidebarRightWork`. I have explained that in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416159/css-show-div-on-hover-not-working/31416219?noredirect=1#comment50811598_31416219), please read it carefully.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry! Stupid me. But when I do that it still only covers the original 100% height and doesn't carry on the with the scroll. https://jsfiddle.net/7mx8mmLd/2/

Comment: Read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416159/css-show-div-on-hover-not-working/31416219?noredirect=1#comment50835907_31416219) again.

Comment: I did set .description to position:fixed; though?

Comment: Oh, I see. That is because you have a `fixed` element inside another `fixed` element. I recommend you to extract `.description` and `.sidebarRightWork` elements out of `.remodal`, and of course, you need to play a bit with your jQuery code. See [this new demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/7mx8mmLd/4/). I also increase the `z-index` in `.description` and `.sidebarRightWork`.

Comment: Hmm I see. Ok. I'll try to muddle though it. Thank you for so much help! I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Always is a pleasure to help ;)